# Kill process signal from Airflow to spark/yarn

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow, hadoop-yarn

Do someone know how next feature can be implemented?
When you marked task in airflow as failed this stops Airflow process however this didn't stoped application running in yarn.

Something similar to

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

when the application running in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions either on success or on failure by using Callback concepts https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html